# Unable to create new answer in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm making a a app in Symfony. I get Entities Answer and Question which are related. I want to enable users to add the answer to the question but I've got the problem with getting question_id to AnswerEntity.
Here it what I came up with:
Answer Controller

```
<?php
/**
 * Answer Controller
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Answer;
use App\Entity\Question;
use App\Form\AnswerType;
use App\Repository\AnswerRepository;
use App\Repository\QuestionRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Flex\PackageFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class AnswerController.
 *
 * @Route("/answer")
 */

class AnswerController extends AbstractController
{
    private $answerRepository;
    private $answer;
    private $paginator;

    /**
     * AnswerController constructor
     *
     * @param \App\Repository\AnswerRepository $answerRepository Answer Repository
     * @param \Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface $paginator
     */
    public function __construct(AnswerRepository $answerRepository, PaginatorInterface $paginator)
    {
        $this->answerRepository = $answerRepository;
        $this->paginator = $paginator;
    }

    /**
     * Index action.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request        HTTP request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response               HTTP response
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/",
     *     methods={"GET"},
     *     name="answer_index",
     * )
     */
    public function index(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator, AnswerRepository $answerRepository): Response
    {
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $answerRepository->queryAll(),
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            AnswerRepository::PAGINATOR_ITEMS_PER_PAGE
        );

        return $this->render(
            'answer/index.html.twig',
            ['pagination' => $pagination]
        );
    }
    /**
     * Create action.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request HTTP request
     *
     * @param \App\Repository\AnswerRepository $answerRepository Answer repository
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response HTTP response
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/create",
     *     methods={"GET", "POST"},
     *     name="answer_create",
     * )
     */
    public function create(Request $request, AnswerRepository $answerRepository): Response
    {
        $answer = new Answer();
        $form = $this->createForm(AnswerType::class, $answer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $answer->setQuestion($this->getQuestion());
            $answerRepository->save($answer);

            $this->addFlash('success', 'answer_created_successfully');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('answer_index');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'answer/create.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView()]
        );
    }
}
```

AnswerForm:

```
<?php
/**
 * Answer type.
 */

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Answer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class AnswerType.
 */
class AnswerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Builds the form.
     *
     * This method is called for each type in the hierarchy starting from the
     * top most type. Type extensions can further modify the form.
     *
     * @see FormTypeExtensionInterface::buildForm()
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder The form builder
     * @param array                                        $options The options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add(
            'AnswerText',
            TextType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'label_answertext',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => ['max_length' => 200],
            ]
        );

        $builder->add(
            'Nick',
            TextType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'label_nick',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => ['max_length' => 64],
            ]
        );
        $builder->add(
            'Email',
            EmailType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'label_email',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => ['max_length' => 64],
            ]
        );

        $builder->add('is_best', HiddenType::class, [
            'data' => '0',
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Configures the options for this type.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver The resolver for the options
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Answer::class]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the prefix of the template block name for this type.
     *
     * The block prefix defaults to the underscored short class name with
     * the "Type" suffix removed (e.g. "UserProfileType" => "user_profile").
     *
     * @return string The prefix of the template block name
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return 'answer';
    }
}
```

and AnswerEntity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AnswerRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AnswerRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="answers")
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $answer_text;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Question::class, inversedBy="answer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $Nick;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $isBest;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAnswerText(): ?string
    {
        return $this->answer_text;
    }

    public function setAnswerText(string $answer_text): void
    {
        $this->answer_text = $answer_text;
    }

    public function getQuestion(): ?Question
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion(?Question $question): void
    {
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNick(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Nick;
    }

    public function setNick(string $Nick): self
    {
        $this->Nick = $Nick;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsBest(): ?int
    {
        return $this->isBest;
    }

    public function setIsBest(int $isBest): self
    {
        $this->isBest = $isBest;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The error is:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYGpo.png

but I have a function getQuestion in AnswerEntity so why doesn't it read that? It read the function setQuestion which is the same Entity.

Is there any chance to do it another way?

Also I'm adding part of my question template code where I get to create_answer

```
            <a href="{{ url('answer_create', {id: questions.id}) }}" title="{{ 'create_answer'|trans }}">
                {{ 'create_answer'|trans }}
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you have the questionId in your route. I think it's a mandatory data to know which question the users tries to answer to.

With a requestParam `id` in the route and a method param typed `Question` the `ParamConverter` can inject the right question in your controller method

```php
/**
    *  ...
     * @Route(
     *     "/create/{id}",
     *     methods={"GET", "POST"},
     *     name="answer_create",
     * )
     */
    public function create(Request $request, AnswerRepository $answerRepository, Question $question): Response
    {
        $answer = new Answer();
        $answer->setQuestion($question);
        // ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error image you posted, there is no `$this->getQuestion()` in a controller unless you create that function.

You can get the question entity by any identifier with Doctrine

```
$question = this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Question::class)->find($question_id);
```

and then you can set the question relation in your `$answer` object

```
$answer->setQuestion($question);
```

Comment: Okay, but I get the getQuestion() in AnswerController (just like setQuestion) and the setQuestion is read by app.

Comment: From my answer, and your error, you can't just use `getQuestion` in your AnswerController like that, it does not make sense. You need to pass the questionId to your controller, likely via GET variable, and get the entity that way.